# Why does my linearSVC fail when I change the penalty to L1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to build a linear SVC model from scikit-learn following the methods laid out in a paper by Hyun et al. (source: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1007608#sec010). In the paper it states:

> SVMs were implemented in scikit-learn, using square hinge loss weighted by class frequency to address class imbalance issues. L1 regularization was included to enforce sparsity for feature selection

I've tried to implement this myself using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from numpy import mean, std

model = LinearSVC(penalty="l1", class_weight='balanced', loss='squared_hinge')
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=5, random_state=127)
n_scores = cross_val_score(model, X_data, Y_data, scoring="accuracy", cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
```

Where the X data involved is a binary matrix of presence/absence of genes; the y data are binary phenotype classifiers (resistant = 1, susceptible = 0). Unfortunately, I cannot give access to the dataset.

However, upon return of my results (n_scores) all values are "nan". When I perform the same task again but set the penalty to l2, I get accuracy scores.

What is happening? And why doesn't it work?

Comment: `cross_val_score` has a parameter `error_score`; set it to `"raise"` and edit the resulting traceback into your question.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thank you for your comment. I did this and identified that the dual parameter should be set to false. I'd also like to credit the authors of the paper who I contacted. They also referred me to this example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html

Answer (score 0):

Dual must be set to False. Example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html